# How to make date category if file contains the date?

Tags: php

I'm stuck.

I think everyone knows Gyazo (fast screenshot taking program), if not [LINK](https://gyazo.com/).
A few months ago I created a folder on my FTP. All the screenshots I make, will be uploaded towards that folder on my FTP.

The image-name is auto-created (yyyymmddhhmmss);

```
Example: 20140921132714.PNG
```

I made a page, which I only can access to view the pictures. But how can I make a category, without connecting a database for extra information.

```
Example:

January 2014
picture1, picture 2, picture 3

December 2013
picture 4, picture 5 etc.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to tell you: I didn't know Gyazo.

Comment: My bad for assuming everyone knows what Gyazo is. Editted

Comment: in your php code make a dynamic array using date('Ym',strtotime($filename)) and insert the relevant files...Still you have to scan whole directory from ftp

Answer (score 0):

so as I understood you need to group these files only by year-month. simple way would be just iterate over it like:

```
$files = ['20140921132714.PNG', '20140921132724.PNG', '20140921132734.PNG'];
$groupedFiles = [];
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $yearmonth = substr($file, 0,6);
    $groupedFiles[$yearmonth][] = $file;
}

var_dump($groupedFiles);
```

now you have array with all your files set yearmonth as key of array. iterate over it and print out your screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Since you used the PHP tag I assume you want to do this in PHP? The only way I see you can do this, without a database (which I would prefer), is:

1: Read the whole folder on your FTP server:

```
$ftp_server = "ftp.example.com";
$ftp_user   = "foo";
$ftp_pass   = "bar";
$ftp_dir    = ".";

// set up a connection or die
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

// try to login
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) 
{
  $list = ftp_nlist($conn_id,$ftp_dir);
} 
else echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user\n";

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

2: Process what you read into date's PHP can understand:

```
foreach ($list as $filename)
{
  // get date of each file
  if (is_numeric(substr($filename,0,14)))
  {
    $year      = substr($filename,0,4);
    $month     = substr($filename,3,2);
    $day       = substr($filename,5,2);
    $hour      = substr($filename,7,2);
    $minute    = substr($filename,9,2);
    $second    = substr($filename,11,2);
    $timestamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$day $hour:$minute:$second")
    $datedList[$timestamp] = $filename;
  }
}
unset($list);
// sort on dates
ksort($datedList);
```

3: Display it on a HTML page:

```
$currentDate = '';
foreach ($datedList as $time=> $filename)
{
  $date = date('F Y',$time);
  if ($currentDate != $date)
  {
    // start new day
    echo "<br><b>$date:</b><br><br>";
    $currentDate = $date;
  }
  // show file
  echo "$filename<br>";
}
```

By changing the `date()` function, using the argument `'F j, Y'`, you can easily show days instead of months. Having the real date's also give you the possibility to not show the filenames themselves, but human-readable date's when the files were made. You can combine step two and three into one step. I split them up for clarity. You will also have to work a bit on the last part if you actually want to make the filenames clickable and show the screenshot.